# How do I add a limited amount of 3 tries to my loop?

Tags: java

I am trying to limit the maximum login attempts to 3. However, my code below uses all the attempts How would I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Final {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Username;
    String Password;

    Password = "bruh"; //username and password for the code
    Username = "bro";

    int totalAttempts = 3; //attempt counter
    
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);//scanner clasees
    System.out.println("Enter Username : ");
    String username = input1.next();

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Password : ");
    String password = input2.next();
    
    //loop also using While statement that i learned from ap classroom
       
    if (username.equals(Username) && password.equals(Password)) {
        System.out.println("Welcome!Username and Password have been validated");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Username or password invalid");
        totalAttempts--;
    }
 
    if (totalAttempts == 0) {
        System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts exceeded");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with loops? `for` or `while`?

Comment: Put the whole input part in a `while(totalAttempts > 0 && !acceptedCredentials)`. Create a variable that you set when the username and password are correct so that it doesn't continue looping. You can also check `acceptedCredentials` after the loop to determine whether they made it through or they exceeded maximum number of attempts.

Comment: Also, you should probably use `.nextLine()` instead of `.next()` to clear your Scanner's buffer.

Comment: Follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. `String Username` should be `String username` or `String userName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int attemptsLeft = 3;
while (attemptsLeft > 0) {
    System.out.println("Enter Username:");
    String username = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    String password = input.nextLine();
    if (username.equals(Username) && password.equals(Password)) {
        System.out.println("Logged in successfully");
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid username or password");
        attemptsLeft--;
    }
}
if (attemptsLeft == 0) {
    System.out.println("You ran out of tries");
}
```

This code pretty much just uses a while loop to repeat the procedure if the credentials are wrong. If the username and password are right, then the line "break" stops the while loop and you can then proceed with your normal functions. Outside the while loop, it checks to make sure that the attemptsLeft are not 0. If they are, it says "You ran out of tries".

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of accomplishing this. One method is to put it inside a `while` loop that breaks when the maximum number of attempts is exceeded OR the credentials provided is valid.

- `try-with-resources` for your Scanner instance so that it gets closed after you are done using it. I don't think I saw that the scanner was getting closed in the original.
- You don't need two Scanners and as mentioned by @TimHunter in the comments you probably want to use `nextLine()` here instead of just `next()`

More changes could be done but that's just a few quick things.

### Updated Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Username = "bro";
    String Password = "bruh";

    int totalAttempts = 3;//attempt counter
    boolean validCredentials = false;

    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in))  {
        while (totalAttempts > 0 && !validCredentials) {

            System.out.println("Enter Username : ");
            String username = scanner.nextLine();


            System.out.println("Enter Password : ");
            String password = scanner.nextLine();
            //loop also using While statement that i learned from ap classroom

            if (username.equals(Username) && password.equals(Password)) {
                validCredentials = true;
                System.out.println("Welcome!Username and Password have been validated");
            }

            else
            {
                totalAttempts--;
                System.out.println("Username or password invalid");
            }

        }
    }

    if (totalAttempts == 0) {
        System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts exceeded");
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, it is quite annoying to receive a downvote and have no idea what it is for.  This has been discussed extensively on meta.  That said, if I can give you my 2 cents, this answer certainly lacks explanation.  The OP is clearly learning Java, so you need to tell them what you did and why your code works, but theirs does not.  Otherwise they don't learn anything.  And the "need to test this" remark doesn't really help.  If you aren't sure if it works, you should test it before posting.  If you're ever unsure about something answer-related, the [answer] page can often be helpful.

Comment: I have a bad habit of putting in the code and updating it to add the explanation or vice versa. Thanks @CharlieArmstrong